# SLComposeViewController always returns true if facebook app is installed on device

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios8, xcode6, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am using SLComposeViewController for facebook sharing, everything is working fine except if i logged out from facebook app from device and then call SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType: Facebook, it returns true and facebook post popup gets displayed and on top of that facebook alert 'Not Logged In' is also shown. if i click on ok button on that alert then Done block gets executed. Appreciate help.

Comment: I am facing exact the same problem, did you find anything?

Comment: Nope, not yet. Awaiting for help.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, can you [report it?](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs), and include a sample repro project?

Comment: anything? still facing the same issue on iOS 9.2.1...

Comment: I have left that project, didn't able to get the cause/solution of problem.